# How long does it take for a Reshus HaRabbim to lose its status?

Tags: shabbat, eruv-chatzerot, maseches-eruvin

If a street typically had 600,000 people travelling on that every day and then for a time period that number dropped, how long would it take for that to make the street no longer a Reshus Harabbim?

For example (this is purely hypothetical. I haven't actually looked into the statistics at all), if Ocean Parkway was a Reshus Harabbim by virtue of having 600,000 people travelling on it every day, and then due to orders to suspend non-essential travel and work because of COVID-19 that number temporarily dropped to 300,000, would it become a Carmelis, which would mean that the Eruv could become valid? How many weeks in a row would it need to have less than 600,000 people travelling on it to go down a level?

I'm assuming that if there was construction and for one week there were less than 600,000 people travelling on it that wouldn't be enough to make it lose it's status of a Reshus Harabbim, but I don't even know if that's true.

Any sources would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This wouldn't really apply according Rav Moshes "kula",but other shittas good q

Comment: Indeed this assumes a very particular definition of reshut harabbim (need 600k, on a particular street, actually walking there, every day). Given how few rishonim held it, it's unlikely you'll get very compelling authoritative proofs in answers. The best I can imagine is it must take more than two days since the market would be closed weekly on Shabbat and there can be a Yom Tov adjacent to it.

Comment: Assuming the 600,000 people requirement refers to a street and not a city if a street has a permanent  government travel restriction then it would probably lose it's Reshus HaRabim status immediately .If it temporary it would probably be no different than a snow storm or any other reason why no one is out one day and keep it's status.

Comment: https://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/reshus-harabim/
this website has alot about this inyan.